# I am using a preferences.framework private framework in objective-c.A header file is not found,?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using a [PrivateFrameworkHeader-iOS-iPhone-5.- / Preferences.framework](https://github.com/masbog/PrivateFrameworkHeader-iOS-iPhone-5.-/blob/master/Preferences.framework/PSListItemsController.h).

A header file is not found. Several of the header files are inheriting from **pscontroller.h**, but **pscontroller.h** is nowhere in the framework.

If anybody knows about this please tell me.

Comment: pls check edited question. If the added hyprelink is the framework u have used then I dont find the **pscontroller.h** file in that entire framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GO to the `Build Phases` of your `target` in Xcode and expand the `Link Binary With Libraries section`. And add the library or framework from your finder , OR Drag preferences.framework over to your expanded `Link Binary With Libraries section`.

i hope this help you...